# Joining 3 tables using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

For some reason my sql statement isn't return the three tables is there something wrong with my sql statement?

```
SELECT user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Profilepix, userinterest.UserId, userinterest.InterestId 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN userinterest ON user.UserId = userinterest.UserId 
INNER JOIN interest ON userinterest.InterestId = interest.InterestId
```

userinterest maps both user and interest together.

EDIT** To add more detail no error is being thrown. The `interest` table is integer indexed so the `userinterest` contains the `userId` and `interestId` and I am trying to map all three and return the record

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Is there an error when trying to run the query? Is no data at all being returned? Or is it just the row(s) you expect not being returned?

Comment: @JustinNiessner there is no error being thrown. The interest table isnt appearing

Comment: From what you describe, there is nothing "wrong" with the syntax of your query. But we can see no data, or table definitions, so without at least 1 of those things (preferable both, but samples of the table data would really help) we have nothing to base recommendations on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to select the fields from the `interest` table if you want to see them. Here I am selecting all the fields with `interest.*`.

```
SELECT user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Profilepix, userinterest.UserId, userinterest.InterestId, interest.*
FROM user 
INNER JOIN userinterest ON user.UserId = userinterest.UserId 
INNER JOIN interest ON userinterest.InterestId = interest.InterestId
```