# Mysql Join 3 Tables and get SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in my database. When i tried to join and sum two of the fields i am getting an error.

[image]

Customers

[image: Advance]

[image: Sales]

What i tried is

```
SELECT b.id,SUM(s.advance) as advance, SUM(c.qty) as sales 
FROM advance s
    INNER JOIN customers b ON s.cust_id = b.id
    INNER JOIN sales c ON b.id  = c.cust_id 
GROUP BY s.cust_id**
```

My output is

[image: o/p]

The o/p i am getting is wrong when there is more than one entry for the key in sales table, The expected o/p was

```
id  advance   sales
2   500       .5
1   500       .25
3   250       .75
```

I Checked these pages still i am getting the wrong output. Any help to resolve the issue is greatly appreciated.

[MySQL JOIN with SUM and 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040948/mysql-join-with-sum-and-3-tables)

[Joining three tables using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709560/joining-three-tables-using-mysql)

[Joining 3 tables using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255335/joining-3-tables-using-mysql)
[Mysql query to join three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257433/mysql-query-to-join-three-tables)

Comment: first sum the sales table and then join it and please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: i tried many ways but problem exists could you suggest me a soln

Comment: then you didn't read the multiple threads to this, your query must be like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e384e4a68292105ca4b7ca2fe6357cd7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d0fa06f367420f78e8cb58c5e7adbe04) for your reference. Please check that out.

I use this query to get your described output (given above).

```
SELECT custID, advance, sales FROM (
SELECT id AS custID FROM ac) c
JOIN (
SELECT SUM(advance) AS advance, cust_id FROM aa GROUP BY cust_id) a ON c.custID = a.cust_id 
JOIN (
SELECT SUM(qty) AS sales, cust_id FROM `as` GROUP BY cust_id) s ON c.custID = s.cust_id ;
```