# how to select all users whose total orders exceed the sum of their diposit?

Tags: mysql, sum

the query bellow, unfortunately returns the wrong total of orders. What I want is to know all users whose total orders exceed the sum of their diposit.

```
SELECT u.id, u.email,u.balance,sum(t.amount - t.fees) as total_disposits ,sum(o.charge) as spent
    FROM USERS u
    INNER JOIN TRANSACTIONS t ON u.id = t.uid
    INNER JOIN ORDERS o ON u.id = o.uid
WHERE total_disposits < spent
    GROUP BY u.id;
```

tables structure :

```
USERS

-----------------------------------
id |  email           | balance 
-----------------------------------
1  |  email1@app.com  | 15.50   
2  |  email2@app.com  | 10.00   
3  |  email3@app.com  | 70.00   
-----------------------------------

TRANSACTIONS

-----------------------------------
id | user_id | amount | fees
-----------------------------------
1  |  1      | 15.50  | 0.50
2  |  2      | 10.00  | 0.50
3  |  2      | 15.00  | 0.50
4  |  3      | 12.50  | 0.50
5  |  1      | 5.50   | 0.50
-----------------------------------

ORDERS

-----------------------------------
id | user_id | charge 
-----------------------------------
1  |  1      | 15.50  
2  |  2      | 10.00  
3  |  2      | 15.00  
4  |  3      | 12.50  
5  |  1      | 5.50   
-----------------------------------

Thank you
```

Comment: You can use output columns in WHERE never. Your output columns expressions uses aggregate functions - you may/must test them in HAVING.

Comment: *tables structure* They'd be provided as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this multiple ways:

1. Using a `subquery`:

```
  SELECT a.id AS user_id,
       a.email,
       a.balance, 
       b.total_deposits,
       c.spent
FROM
  USERS a 
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT t.uid, 
          SUM(t.amount - t.fees) AS total_deposits
    FROM TRANSACTIONS t
    GROUP BY t.uid) b 
  ON a.id = b.uid
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT o.uid, 
          SUM(o.charge) AS spent
    FROM ORDERS o
    GROUP BY o.uid) c 
  ON a.id = c.uid
WHERE b.total_deposits < c.spent
```

2. Using a Common Table Expression (`CTE`):

```
   WITH b AS 
  (SELECT t.uid, 
          SUM(t.amount - t.fees) AS total_deposits
    FROM TRANSACTIONS t
    GROUP BY t.uid),
  c AS 
  (SELECT o.uid, 
          SUM(o.charge) AS spent
    FROM ORDERS o
    GROUP BY o.uid)
SELECT a.id AS user_id,
       a.email,
       a.balance, 
       b.total_deposits,
       c.spent
FROM
  USERS a 
  INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.uid
  INNER JOIN c ON a.id = c.uid
WHERE b.total_deposits < c.spent
```

**Result:**

| user_id | email | balance | total_deposits | spent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email1@app.com | 15.50 | 20.00 | 21.00 |
| 2 | email2@app.com | 10.00 | 24.00 | 25.50 |
| 3 | email3@app.com | 70.00 | 12.00 | 12.50 |

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Je3-W3nG).

The reason for this is you cannot use a column alias in your `WHERE` clause, the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) states this:

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
> This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
> evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined. For
> example, the following query is illegal:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name
  WHERE cnt > 0 GROUP BY id;
```

You can also read more about it in the following previous questions:

- [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an
  error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)
- [WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905292/where-vs-having/18710763#18710763)

**Final Note:** your `GROUP BY` was incorrect, it contained the `id` column but not the `email` and `balance` column which will throw an aggregation error. To include the `email` and `balance` without adding it to your `GROUP BY`, you can use a `JOIN` as I did in my examples above.

**UPDATE:** I've added the column `uid` to the `JOIN`'s above. The column `id` was the only provided id column in your sample data. I've also updated my *Queries*, *Result*, and *Fiddle* to reflect your *Answer* above which shows you wanted the `SUM`'s to occur outside of the `JOIN`'s.

Comment: both of the queries doesnt return anything ,(big thanks for the final note)

Comment: @JozephOFATTOLE I've updated my answer, you seem to have a column you're using for your `JOINS` called `uid`, I've added it to my answer, I was using the `id` column that you provided in your sample data above.

Comment: @JozephOFATTOLE I've updated my answer once again to reflect your Answer above using the `SUM`'s outside of the `JOIN`'s. My first query is similar to yours except I'm `SELECT`ing from the user table directly, there's technically no need to put it in a subquery like you did. Also, check out the `CTE` query. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, u.balance, total_deposits, spent 
FROM (SELECT id AS user_id ,balance FROM USERS ) u 
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(charge) AS spent, uid FROM ORDERS  GROUP BY uid) o 
    ON u.user_id = o.uid 
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(amount) - SUM(fees) AS total_deposits, uid FROM TRANSACTIONS GROUP BY uid) t 
    ON u.user_id = t.uid 
WHERE spent > total_deposits
```

the query inspired from the answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71702680/3641989

IMPORTANT : **There are no relationships between these tables**